# Скрыть - отобразить DIV

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html5

Доброго дня, что имею:

```
<div class="inline-select">
<a data-value="8" href="#8" class="not-color-block selected">material_1</a>
<a data-value="10" href="#10" class=" not-color-block">material_2</a>
<a data-value="170" href="#170" class=" not-color-block">material_3</a>
<a data-value="171" href="#171" class=" not-color-block">material_4</a>
<a data-value="172" href="#172" class=" not-color-block">material_5</a>
<input type="hidden" data-feature-id="9" class="sku-feature" name="features[9]" value="8">

<div id="XXX}">
                <div class="opisanie_1">3123</div>
                <div class="opisanie_2">3333</div>
                <div class="opisanie_3">444</div>
                <div class="opisanie_4">444</div>
                <div class="opisanie_5">444</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Как мне показать `DIV.opisanie_1` когда `A[data-value='10']` с классом `.selected`?

Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Если не используется какой-либо фреймворк, то написать что-то вроде такой функции.

```
setInterval(function () {
  if ($('a[data-value="10"]').hasClass('selected')) {
    $('.opisanie-1').show();
  }
}, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы добавил каждому А атрибут типа data-block-class="opisanie_1", и дальше использовал что-то типа такого

```
jQuery(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    var t = jQuery(this),
        class = t.data('block-class'),
        div = jQuery('#XXX .' + class);

    t.siblings().removeClass('selected');
    t.addClass('selected');

    div.siblings().hide();
    div.show();

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну раз были варианты на JS, добавлю и CSS решение для разнообразия, не зря же там тэг стоит. Не очень гибко конечно, но по заданным условиям.

```
#XXX div{
    display:none
}

a[data-value="10"].selected ~ #XXX .opisanie_1{
    display:block
}
```